# Что делать, если переменная цикла инициализирована до него?

Tags: java, for

Только вот начал изучать Java ( месяц уже, но не суть, я еще не разработчик, конечно).

Написал программу для вычисления факториала. Код ниже. Однако есть один вопросик.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int fact = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int sum=1;


    for (fact; fact >0; fact--)
    {
        sum *= fact;
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Что мне не нравится. В строке

```
for (fact; fact >0; fact--)
```

компилятор усердно указывает : fact -  не выражение, ай-яй-яй!
Я хотел чтобы факториал, который вводится и был главной переменной в цикле, однако надо ему что-то присвоить. Перебрав разные варианты, махинации, я удивился(смешанные чувства, вроде удивился, а вроде нет), что заменив ту строку кода на эту, не было никакой ошибки и программа правильно отрабатывала свое.

```
for (fact=fact; fact >0; fact--)
```

Мол выражение есть, так что пусть работает цикл.  Но это как мне кажется, не эстетично и не совсем красивый код ( грех мне, новичку, говорить что красивый код, а что нет, но я подумал что наверняка должны быть другие способы решения. Конечно это не проблема, но все же).

Comment: можно было все объявление fact перенести в `for`, а так же можно было просто ничего не писать

Comment: @Grundy Звучит очень логично, однако я больше интересуюсь больше тем, можно ли ввести какую то переменную в цикл for, и работать с ней, не объявляя выражение

Comment: что значит _ввести какую то переменную в цикл for, и работать с ней, не объявляя выражение_ - любая переменная объявленная до цикла доступна в цикле и с ней можно работать

Comment: @Grundy Верно, я просто неправильно выразил свои мысли, имея виду, использовать ранее объявленную переменную в качестве счетчика, без присваивания ей какого либо значения в (незнаю как назвать. Шапка что ли? То место где 
for (fact; fact >0; fact--)

Comment: А зачем туда что-то добавлять если можно не добавлять?

Comment: @Grundy А вот то, что можно не добавлять, и пропустить один из элементов, я только что узнал, прочитав ответ ниже) Теперь все выглядит намного яснее

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Элементы `for` не являются обязательными, можете пропустить первое выражение, если оно Вами не используется:

```
for(;fact>0; fact--) {
    ...
```

Но этот цикл выглядит непривычно по двум причинам:

1. Обычно для счетчика цикла используют отдельную переменную. Это правило не то чтобы обязательно, но цикл со счетчиком — очень простой элемент, он должен легко считываться, а не удивлять разработчика.
2. Переменные названы как-то странно: счетчик чисел почему-то называется `fact` хотя факториал в нем никогда не окажется, сам же факториал назван `sum`.

Поэтому лучше использовать для пробегания по числам отдельную переменную и все переименовать как следует.

```
int max = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
int fact = 1;
for (int i = max; i > 0; i--) {
    fact *= i;
}
```

Для пущей простоты, можно перебирать множители по возрастанию:

```
for(int i = 1; i<=max; i++) {
...
```

Comment: Выражаю вам благодарность) Согласен с вами по всем двумя пунктам, открыл что-то новое для себя, узнав что элемент можно пропустить

Comment: @ВладКовальчук Пожалуйста! Успехов в обучении в труде :)

Comment: Зашедши к вам в профиль, я увидел интересную информацию, что вы из Алматы) ( я из Астаны). К сожалению, я не нашел функции Личных сообщений , и хотел бы немножко отклониться от темы и задать вопросик .  Где вы учились и где рекомендуете учиться? Я только в 10 классе, однако я планирую через 2 года изучения программирования/прикладной информатики пойти на 1) СПбГУ ИТМО, МФТИ , СПбСТУ ( победы в множестве олимпиад по физике, думаю, помогут мне, хоть и иду на программиста). Но все же, может и у нас на Родине есть хорошие, очень даже неплохие университеты?

Comment: @ВладКовальчук у Вас хорошие варианты, насколько я понимаю :) я учился в КБТУ, тогда было неплохо (закончил в 2010м), сейчас мне, честно говоря, сложно судить о положении дел в высшем образовании что у нас что за рубежом, т.ч. ничего не могу посоветовать, к сожалению.

Answer (score 2):

А можно и вот так

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int fact = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

for (int i = fact - 1;i > 0;i--) {
   fact *= i;
}

System.out.println(fact);
```